# ImageBackground not working, when used in root of the app

Tags: react-native, imagebackground

I want to apply a gradient background image in my react-native app, so instead of putting `ImageBackground` in every component I have put it in my `app.js` to wrap all the screens under it. But only background image is visible, no other content is visible over the back image. This is my app.js

```
render() {
        return (
      <View 
      style={{flex:1}}>
         <ImageBackground style={{ flex: 1,
        resizeMode: 'cover'}} source={APP_BACKGROUND_IMAGE}  >
         <View style={styles.container}>
         <AppNavigator />
         </View>
         </ImageBackground>
</View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{ 
  position:'absolute',
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0
},
});
```

This is AppNavigator

```
render() {
        return (
        <MainStackNavigator/>
        );
    }
}
```

This is MainStackNavigator:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import OnBoarding from '../screens/OnBoarding';
import LoginContainer from '../screens/Login/LoginContainer';
export const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    OnBoardingScreen: {screen: OnBoarding},
    LoginScreen: {screen: LoginContainer}
}):
```

This is my first screen OnBoarding:

```
render() {
    return (
        <AppIntro customStyles={{
                dotStyle: {
                    width: 6,
                    height: 6,
                },

            }} showDoneButton={false} showSkipButton={false}

                onSlideChange={this.onSlideChangeHandle} >
                {this.getOnBoardingScreens()}
            </AppIntro>

        );
    }
}
```

Can someone tell what wrong I am doing ? I have tried couple of things but nothing worked. :( 
P.S: When I call `<OnBoarding/>` directly under `ImageBackground` in app.js it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Container with the style defined and having gradient background. It's a straight forward way to set background in root of your app.
1.Import the Image you want to set in background.
import Background from '../images/background_image.png';
2. Use inline style of your root element, and use the imported image as below.
backgroundImage: `url(${Background}

Comment: what different I am doing?

Comment: Use stylesheet insteadof using ImageBackground Tag. Try Container with inline CSS style.

Comment: I have tried with `Image` component and giving it styles but it doesn't work

Comment: I am using react-native and there is no such style property that I am aware of. Can you please provide a snack.io implementation if possible ?

Comment: Here is the simplest example by Kyle Banks. https://kylewbanks.com/blog/fullscreen-background-image-in-react-native  go through it and create BackgoundImage Component Accordingly.

Comment: this is a deprecated version we can't put children inside `<Image>` anymore.

Comment: try ImageBackround insted Image, with the abouve given example